# How to make this text view in react native, a tag before text view, and text can be multi-line

Tags: react-native, text

I want to make this text view in react native, a tag before text view, and text can be multi-line. But react native not like h5 flexbox, text alway start at the beginning of the line.

I want to make.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trying  this way

```
function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          width: 500,
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "pink",
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ width: 50, height: 20, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
        <View style={{ width: 50, height: 20, backgroundColor: "red" }} />           
        <Text>Test 123 </Text>
        <Text>Test 123 </Text>
        ....
        <View style={{ width: 50, height: 20, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Example code [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hooks-4bvr8o?from-embed)

Comment: This is not work in react native ios.

Comment: @user10965730 show your code

Comment: maybe it only work in web. 
https://gist.github.com/Innei/b730efe0954e7b0dd3873e01a50d3e32
<View><Text>Tag</Text></View> Tag is not render in ios.